# Обработка текста

Tags: php

Есть текст

```
   Ибица На телевидении 
    MMS :/ / 81.174.67.45/ibizaontv 
    ТМФ танца 
    MMS :/ / 94.75.250.121:554 / 39987 @ 662299? MSWMExt =. ASF 
    Worm ТВ 
    MMS :/ / wms.global-streaming.net/04988
```

Нужно обработать это в array массив

```
array 1
Ибица На телевидении , MMS :/ / 81.174.67.45/ibizaontv
```

Как с помощью php выдергивать строчку 1 и 2 и так все сначала в новый массив

Answer (score 1, accepted):

предлагаю сделать двумерный массив

'myfile.txt'- входной файл.

код

```
$filearray=file('myfile.txt');
$outarray=array();
$sub_array=array();
foreach ($filearray as $key => $value) 
    {
       $sub_array[]=$value;
       if (count($sub_array)==2)
       {
           $outarray[]=$sub_array;
           $sub_array=array();
       }
    }
var_dump($outarray);
```

результат

```
array(3) { 
   [0]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(26) " Ибица На телевидении " [1]=> string(38) " MMS :/ / 81.174.67.45/ibizaontv " } 
   [1]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(16) " ТМФ танца " [1]=> string(66) " MMS :/ / 94.75.250.121:554 / 39987 @ 662299? MSWMExt =. ASF " } 
   [2]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(14) " Worm ТВ " [1]=> string(43) " MMS :/ / wms.global-streaming.net/04988" } 
}
```